# ejabberd behavior b/w user disconnected vs user unavailable

Tags: ejabberd, xmppframework

What is the ejabbered behavior for user who is un-expectedly disconnected from internet

vs

user who explicitly sent an 'unavailable' presence?

Would they both be considered offline (for both single user chat or MUC)?

I want a behavior where if a user is disconnected from internet, offline messages to be sent

If user sent a explicit unavailble presence, I dont want offline messages to be sent.

How can that be accomplished? I can write my hook. But I need to know in which situations, the hook will be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user gets offline, the default behaviour is the same, no matter which method is used (explicit session close or unvoluntary disconnect). This is per XMPP specification.

If you want to customise the behaviour, it will not be easy as there is no way to know the reason why a user if offline.
What I would do: I would use the last module and support an optional reason for disconnect and store it. When you disconnect unvoluntarily, I would modify code to store reason being something like "timeout". When you disconnect explicitely, I would store another flag. When you get an offline message, you can then check the reason from being offline coming from mod_last storage.

Comment: if you terminate client - is it possible to keep session active,  just ignore TCP disconnects, not presences. XEP - 0198 suggests the same

Comment: Not as standard and not forever. If you have to restart a node in ejabberd cluster for example, all session will be closed anyway.

Comment: As I mention: Add a custom reason field in your presence unavailable tag from client.

Comment: Not clear...but thanks...I will think more....because if disconnected unvoluntarily...then no presence stanza will be sent from client right? or does ejabbered sends presence to running modules when stream/session is disconnected unvoluntarily

Comment: When the session end, ejabberd code knows it and you can act accordingly in your code.